# Does Kendo Grid work in Mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, monodevelop, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Just a simple question I've been unable to track down an answer to. If anyone knows I would appreciate if you would be willing to share your knowledge here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean Kendo UI Grid for ASP.NET MVC. Yes, it works in Mono. In fact we are actively using Mono for development.

Comment: That's amazing, and you do mean the Kendo MVC and not just the OpenSource right?

Comment: Ok great, I can start a new question if need be, but are you using FluentNhibernate? Nhibernate.Linq? I'm having trouble with Linq's Method Syntax and I'm using every .dll that I'm aware of it needing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Perhaps a new question would be better.